# Protobuf-net serialization InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have an custom object I'm trying to serialize using Protobuf-net and the following exception is thrown:

InvalidOperationException was unhandled:  Cannot write a Variant header until the String data has been written

The thing I'm finding interesting is that at no point in my object graph is there a string that is being serialized.  Has anyone ever seen an error like this before and is there a known cause/fix?  Thank you

Comment: In this context, "the String data" is talking about the protobuf wire specification, where "string" is a *wire-type* that doesn't necessarily mean "a string of text". Basically, it is usually "header, value, header, valye, ..." where the *header* includes (in very compressed form) the wire-type of the following value; hence, if it found itself writing "header, header", it knows that something is wrong, and it is complaining that no value was written for the first header, which happens to have been of type: "string". Overall though, I *suspect* this is a long-fixed bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a lot like the bug here:

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=218.

Are you serializing a zero length byte[] at some point in your object?

Comment: There was a zero length byte array on all occasions where this error was occurring.  I've stopped zero length arrays from happening and that seems to have fixed things.  I will probably try a later build of protobuf-net and see if that fixes things more properly

Comment: @mcd which build are you using when this happens?

Comment: @MarcGravell I think it's 2.0.0.404